# Android renders RGB values wrong. How to fix it?

Tags: android, colors, background, png, android-actionbar

I have very strange problem. To explain it, I will use this simple example. I'm trying to change action bar backgroung color (or button color, it is no metter). So I use following theme, which I apply to my app.

```
<style name="Theme.App" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.App.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.App.ActionBar" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#262626</item>
    <item name="android:icon">@drawable/actionbar_logo</item>
    <item name="android:displayOptions">showHome</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

As you can see I use **#262626** color as a background of ab. On my mockups in Adobe Photoshop and Illustrator it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA7Re.png

But in my emulator (and even on my G Nexus) it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBSTL.png

As you can see it uses different color. It is **#212421**, instead of #262626.

I'm tried to use #ff262626, tried to use 9-patch png (with the same color) as a background, but the result is the same.
I found some questions, which look like mine. Some of answers sounds like: "some Android devices do not support 32-bit png (or 16 and so on)".

**So the questions are:** How to fix it? How to make actionbar looks like I want? How do you create your own png-resources, which looks good? What am I doing wrong?

---

I would greatly appreciate for your help. Alex.
P.S. *Sorry for my English*:)

Comment: the two images are same

Comment: Check your colour settings in photoshop (edit->color settings). And/Or read up on colour management: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_management

Comment: @Neoh, no, this is not.

Comment: @Jave, I checked it. I set all settings as mentioned here: http://bjango.com/articles/photoshop/. But it doesn't help me at all:(

Comment: @AlexMomotov, did you eventually find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @iRuth, Yep. It was sRGB (color managment). Try to turn it off in your PS or AI. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB